# is it possible to define acronyms which won´t be mentioned in glossary

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am writing my thesis and use the \usepackage{glossary} for my list of symbols and acronyms. I want to use symbols for chemicals (like argon Ar or hydrogen H) in order to be mentioned with its symbol name when it is first mentioned in the text, but it shouldn´t be listed in the glossary.

Is there a way to define acronyms which won't be mentioned in the glossary? I thought about an option in the \newacronym command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by defining a new ignored glossary and assigning acronyms to this ignored glossary.

The following is a MWE assuming that xindy is used to alphabetically  sort the list of acronyms. The resulting list of acronyms of this MWE only contins 'A', while 'H' is not listed.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[xindy,acronyms,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\newignoredglossary{ignored}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym[type=ignored]{H}{H}{hydrogen}
\newacronym{A}{A}{not ignored entry}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acronym,style=long]

\gls{H} \gls{A} \gls{H}

\end{document}
```